# `Class not found` error even though class is defined as a modal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following method in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $data = session()->get('dmca');
        // return $data;
        $notice = Notice::open($date);
        $notice->useTemplate($request->input('template'));
        $notice->save();
        return Notice::first();
    }
```

When the controller runs i get the following error:

[image]

Now i do have the following modal class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notice extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'provider_id',
        'infringing_title',    
        'infringing_link',    
        'original_link',    
        'original_description',    
        'template',    
        'content_removed'
    ];


    public static function open(array $attributes) {
        return new static($attributes); 
    } 

    public function useTemplate($template) {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

}
```

Now why am i getting this error in laravel class not found , even though i have this class defined ??

Answer (score 5):

Just use `use` keyword at the top of your controller class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Notice; // <------------------ use here
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = session()->get('dmca');
        // return $data;
        $notice = Notice::open($date);
        $notice->useTemplate($request->input('template'));
        $notice->save();
        return Notice::first();
    }
}
```

> The `use` keyword helps php to recognize the class `Notice` within a certain namespace

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to the top of a controller:

```
use App\Notice;
```

Or use full namespace:

```
$notice = \App\Notice::open($date);
```

Comment: i get this error http://imgur.com/k0XQdAm . as soon as i submit the form .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik you've asked the question about this error today and I've already answered it and added correct code to my answer. Please check it, it will fix new error you get.

Comment: @Alecey , yes your answer of today is right , but now i am getting this error when i submit the form :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130607/discussion-between-alexander-solonik-and-alexey-mezenin).